# Compile faster_rcnn_cplusplus and caffe example with correct protobuf

Tags: c++, caffe, protobuf-c

I Installed [protobuffer 3.3.0 form a source code](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/src) instead of version 2.6.1 used "make" to make caffe, tested it, and tried to compile [faster_rcnn_cplusplus](https://github.com/HermannHesse/faster_rcnn_cplusplus)

Unfortunately it gives ma an error:

```
/home/adzhus/Workspace/Faster-RCNN-CPP-1/faster_rcnn_cplusplus/py-faster-rcnn/caffe-fast-rcnn/include/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h:17:2: error: #error This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is...
```

Path is seems to be correct.
I also checked  `protoc --version` which gives me `libprotoc 3.3.0`, but for some reason `apt-get upgrade libprotobuf-dev` gives me `ibprotobuf-dev is already the newest version (2.6.1-1.3).`

Could someone,please, advice how to fix the compilation error ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved for me.
I just copied caffe.pb.h from  `...caffe-fast-rcnn/build/src/caffe/proto`  to `...caffe-fast-rcnn/include/caffe/proto`